# How to get the top-k frequent words in spark without sorting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark, we could easily use map reduce to count the word appearance time, and use sort to get the top-k frequent words,

```
// Sort locally inside node, keep only top-k results,
// no network communication

val partialTopK = wordCount.mapPartitions(it => {
    val a = it.toArray
    a.sortBy(-_._2).take(10).iterator
}, true)


// Collect local top-k results, faster than the naive solution

val collectedTopK = partialTopK.collect
collectedTopK.size


// Compute global top-k at master,
// no communication, everything done on the master node

val topK = collectedTopK.sortBy(-_._2).take(10)
```

But I want to know is there a better solution that avoid sorting at all?

Comment: To get the top based on some value then you must sort somewhere. If you want speed you might be able to use blinkdb though

Comment: @JustinPihony, that's not true. You can get the top-n without sorting everything (basically because you don't need to sort things you know are not in the top n). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`takeOrdered`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#takeOrdered(num:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):Array[T])

> Returns the first k (smallest) elements from this RDD as defined by
>   the specified implicit Ordering[T] and maintains the ordering.

or [`top`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#top(num:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):Array[T])

> Returns the top k (largest) elements from this RDD as defined by the
>   specified implicit Ordering[T].

There are several other SO questions/answers that seem at least partial duplicates too